# ruby - error occurred while evaluating nil.[]= ... how to iterate thru multi-dimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, iterator

I have a multi-dimensional array called `my_ids_and_names`
It should probably be a hash but lets leave it as an array for now :)

I create it with: `my_own_array = Array.new[10],[2]`

I have a variable @my_ids which has the id's that I want.

I populate it within a method like this:

```
# Setup
@my_ids_and_names = Array.new[10],[2]
@my_ids.each do |cid|
  @my_ids_and_names[cid][1] = my_id
  @my_ids_and_names[cid][2] = MyModel.find(my_id).internal_name
end
@my_ids_and_names
```

Now I want to retrieve information in views.
I am trying:

```
<% @campaign_ids_and_names.each do |cid, nm| %>
  "various bits of code..."
  var_for_id = cid
  var_for_nm = nm
<% end %>
```

Will the cid and nm be set correctly?

I want the loop to be able to spit out the cid/names as in

```
id  name
4   brick
9   tile
45  grout
```

Right now I am getting `The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]=` in the `setup`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you fire up `irb` console, you'll see that `Array.new[10],[2]` is not creating an array you wanted, instead it creates the following array:

```
[nil, [2]]
```

If you want to create a new array with 10 array elements, use the following constructor:

```
Array.new(10, [])
```

#### Update 1

But as reading your question further I can see that you need a `Hash` instead of an `Array`, and you should keep in mind that ruby starts to index from `0` instead of `1`.

So:

```
@my_ids_and_names = Hash.new
@my_ids.each do |cid|
  @my_ids_and_names[cid] = Array.new
  @my_ids_and_names[cid][0] = my_id
  @my_ids_and_names[cid][1] = MyModel.find(my_id).internal_name
end
@my_ids_and_names
```

Which can be further simplified to:

```
@my_ids_and_names = {}
@my_ids.each do |cid|
  @my_ids_and_names[cid] = [ my_id, MyModel.find(my_id).internal_name ]
end
@my_ids_and_names
```

#### Update 2

But that won't work with your `each` loop what you've provided, so I would use the following code instead:

```
@my_ids_and_names = {}
@my_ids.each do |cid|
  @my_ids_and_names[cid] = MyModel.find(my_id).internal_name
end
@my_ids_and_names
```

This will create a `Hash` with `cid` keys and the `internal_name` of `MyModels` as values.

Comment: +1 accepted. Sounds good I will go with the hash then.  I am more familiar with two dimensional arrays but I guess it's time to think more rubyish.  I always think of hashes as associative arrays but I guess the syntax just has to be right :)

Comment: I like the Update 2 also, I am going to use that as it looks cleaner.  Thank You!

Comment: btw is `@my_ids_and_names[cid] = [ my_id, MyModel.find(my_id).internal_name ]
` the same as `@my_ids_and_names{cid => MyModel.find(my_id).internal_name }` and would that still work the same in my `.each` loop output ?

Comment: That't wont be the same, because they would be different objects. But yes, maybe the `.each` loop would work the same.